# CloseableHttpClient habilitar follow redirect

Tags: java, apache, web-crawler

Estou tentando implementar um crawler usando um clinete http da apache (org.apache.hc.client5.http).

Na primeira parte eu preciso fazer um Request GET desligando o FOLLOW REDIRECT.
Para isso usei o seguinte cógido:

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .disableRedirectHandling()
            .build()) {

        URI uri = new URI("https://MINHA URL");
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);

        String location;
        String cookie;

        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget)) {


                location = response.getFirstHeader("Location");
                cookie = response.getFirstHeader("Set-Cookie");

        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

A segunda parte do crawler deve realizar um Request POST para a URL retornada no location, e setar o cookie. Entretando para essa requisição eu preciso que o cliente faça o follow redirect.

Como para criar o cliente o código utilizado destivou o redirect, conforme exibido abaixo no disableRedirectHandling:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(this.cm)
            .disableRedirectHandling()
            .build()
```

Minha dúvida é como eu devo fazer para habilitar e desabilitar o **disableRedirectHandling** ?

Na classe **CloseableHttpClient** não identifiquei um método que me permita isso.

Como devo proceder para fazer essas modificações no cliente HTTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode ter mais de um objeto definido no try with resources, só precisa chamar de nomes diferentes. Você pode usar a classe HttpClients para buildar o segundo client.

```java
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .disableRedirectHandling()
                .build(); 
             CloseableHttpClient httpClientRedirect = HttpClients.custom()
                       .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                       .build()) {

    // seu código aqui

    }
```